# Prove that $\sum _{k=1}^n\:k\left(n-1\right)^{k-1}\binom{n}{k} =n^n$

Tags: summation, combinations

> Show that
>   $$\sum _{k=1}^n\:k\left(n-1\right)^{k-1}\begin{pmatrix}n\\ k\end{pmatrix}=n^n.$$

So far I've done:
\begin{align*} \sum _{k=1}^n\:\left(n-1\right)^{k-1}\frac{n!}{\left(k-1\right)!\left(n-k\right)!} 
&=\ \sum _{k=1}^n\:n\left(n-1\right)^{k-1}\begin{pmatrix}n-1\\ k-1\end{pmatrix}\\
&= \sum _{k=1}^n\:2^{n-1}\cdot n\left(n-1\right)^{k-1} \\
&= n2^{n-1}\cdot \sum _{k=1}^n\:\left(n-1\right)^{k-1}.
\end{align*}
And got stuck in here, though it doesn't seem to be close to the correct answer ($\ n^n$) anyway... Could I get some hints on how to get this one done? Thank you. *looked for this a while, hopefully it's not a duplicate

Comment: Where does $2^{n-1}$ come from?

Comment: The sum of all combinations n-1,k-1.

Comment: @Alexander you seem to be forgetting that $$\sum (a\cdot b) \neq \left( \sum a \right) \cdot \left( \sum b \right)$$

Comment: @userSeventeen you're right, thanks for letting me know about the mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are very near to the full solution.

After setting $j=k-1$, by the [Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Theorem_statement) we obtain
$$\sum _{k=1}^n\:k\left(n-1\right)^{k-1}\binom{n}{k}=
n\sum _{k=1}^n\left(n-1\right)^{k-1}\binom{n-1}{k-1}\\=n\sum _{j=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{j}\left(n-1\right)^{j}1^{n-1-j}=n((n-1)+1)^{n-1}=n^n.$$

Comment: I don't get the second to last "=". Could you please expend on that?

Comment: By binomial theorem $n^{n-1}(a+b)^{n-1}=\sum _{j=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{j}a^jb^{n-1-j}$ with $a=n-1$ and $b=1$.

Comment: I see it now, thank you.

Comment: @Alexander Well done!!

Answer (score 0):

You get
$$n\sum_{k=1}^n(n-1)^{k-1}\binom{n-1}{k-1}
=n\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(n-1)^j\binom{n-1}{j}
=n\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{j}x^j$$
where $x=n-1$ and I made the substitution $j=k-1$.
Can you see where to go from here?